# Vagrant: Ansible set hosts entries via provision

Tags: vagrant, ansible, hosts

i have a question again. I'm looking for a possibility to set hosts entries for domains in vagrant ansible without using my local and guest hosts files.

I read something about the inventory file, so tried it. The following content is in the file itself:

```
[myvm]
the-vm.local
```

Here is the error I got from

```
==> myvm: Running provisioner: ansible...
ANSIBLE_FORCE_COLOR=true ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING=false PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 ansible-playbook --private-key=/Users/me/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key --user=vagrant --limit='myvm' --inventory-file=ansible/hosts -v ansible/playbook.yml

PLAY [all] ******************************************************************** 

GATHERING FACTS *************************************************************** 
fatal: [the-vm.local] => SSH encountered an unknown error during the connection. We recommend you re-run the command using -vvvv, which will enable SSH debugging output to help diagnose the issue

TASK: [Required packages present] ********************************************* 
FATAL: no hosts matched or all hosts have already failed -- aborting


PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************** 
       to retry, use: --limit @/Users/me/playbook.retry

the-vm.local               : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0   

Ansible failed to complete successfully. Any error output should be
visible above. Please fix these errors and try again.
```

Any clue how to solve that or is there any other way to do it?

Thanks in upfront!

Comment: Did you find any answer? @maTu

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The problem lies where ansible is running on our local machine and the vagrant VM is using NAT.

The answer involves setting the VM network to bridged so that ansible can resolve the hostname or ip from the machine it is executing from (Vagrantfile modification):

```
config.vm.network :public_network
```

During "vagrant up" the console will ask you to specify which network interface to bridge to.

```
==> default: Available bridged network interfaces:
1) en1: Wi-Fi (AirPort)
2) en0: Ethernet
3) en3: Thunderbolt 1
4) bridge0
5) p2p0
    default: What interface should the network bridge to?
```

Source: http://docs.ansible.com/guide_vagrant.html